# android: unable to get updated location

Tags: android

i'm new to java and android, i'm building an app to send user's current location via sms but my code always sends the same location. When I remove Last known location from my code i did not get any location. please i humbly request to solve my issue.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener  {


long time = 5 * 1000; 
long distance = 10; 
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
Location location;
String device_id;
double latitude ;
double longitude;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

    String phoneNo = "+923362243969";


@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    System.out.println("alarm receiver....");
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    context.startService(service);

    //Start App On device restart
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Intent App = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    App.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(App);
    }


    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    device_id = tm.getDeviceId();  // returns IMEI number  

    try {
        LocationManager   locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
               locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time,distance, this);
               Log.d("Network", "Network");
               latitude = location.getLatitude();
               longitude = location.getLongitude();    
               String Text =  " From Network: Latitude = " + latitude  +" Longitude = " + longitude + " Device Id: " + device_id;
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                this.abortBroadcast(); 

                    }
                }
            }


            else {
              if  (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,time,distance, this);
                       Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                       latitude  =  location.getLatitude();
                       longitude =  location.getLongitude();
                       String Text =  " From GPS: Latitude = " + latitude +" Longitude = " + longitude + " Device Id: " + device_id;
                            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, Text, null, null);
                            Log.i("Send SMS", "");
                            this.abortBroadcast(); 
                            }                    

                        }
                    }       

               }  

            }    


    } catch (Exception e) {

        //  Toast.makeText(context, "no connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          e.printStackTrace();
    }                         }     
       @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Update your location in `onLocationChanged()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set you updated location to Location object :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   this.location = location;
}
```

Comment: thanks i also want to remove LastknownLocation() because i never want to get last location. plz i request you to edit my code.

Comment: please not approve ans if your problem is not resolve.

Comment: this is the second problem which i did not mention in the code.

Comment: should i ask it a new question.

Comment: blocked from asking questions.. are u available somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

There various ways to get Location on Android, whenever you request location it tries to get from GPS and if it fails to get, you need to get it from Network. In case of Network location you will get "Same" location most of the time because network gets its location from tower nearby.

You can you googleplay Fuse api to for checking optimal location.

Regards